# Android Switch in Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I want to have a Switch in the Bottom Navigation to set the online/offline state of the user like below Image:

[image]

The menu itself should be dynamic so i built it manually with:

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.navigation_dashboard, Menu.NONE, "").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_app)
```

Is there a way to achieve this and add a switch to this? I accomplished the this in iOS by setting a switch to the frame of the bottom navigation bar item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about having the button color change, when that item is selected?  If so, this is done automatically for you, using the `BottomNavigationView` component.

Do be aware, that you will need to supply a "StateListDrawable" (this is a fancy way to say list of icons, that represent different selected states) instead of just a drawable for this icon:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want a native Switch in the menu - not just an image